# Como verificar se um valor está em um DataFrame com Pandas no Python?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, dataframe

Eu criei o seguinte DataFrame:

```
lista_assuntos = pd.read_excel('autchas/lista_assuntos.xlsx')
```

Quando eu rodo `print(lista_assuntos['Assuntos'])` é impresso:

```
0                     Conexão
1                      Outros
2             Ponto Adicional
3         Teste de Velocidade
4                  Reativação
```

Quando faço `print('Outros' in lista_assuntos['Assuntos'])` é impresso `False`.

Mas não era pra retornar `True`, uma vez que existe a string 'Outros' dentro de 'lista_assuntos'? Ou se tem uma forma correta de conferir se o valor está em um DataFrame.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O retorno de `lista_assuntos['Assuntos']` é, presumidamente, um objeto `Series`, que é tratado como um dicionário, onde o índice é a chave, com seu valor correspondente.

Ao usar o operador `in` diretamente no retorno, ocorrerá iteração sobre as "índices [chaves]", como num dicionário (no exemplo, [0,1,2,3,4]).

Para iterar sobre os valores, você deve utilizar o atributo "values".

`print('Outros' in lista_assuntos['Assuntos'].values)` deve retornar True, pois vai iterar sobre ['Conexão', 'Outros', 'Ponto Adicional', ...].

Referência: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html

Comment: Funcionou aqui, muito obrigado!